# How to identify the first iteration in a for..in loop

Tags: javascript

We have a loop like this:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) {
      // Here need operation only for first iteration (1)
      // Other operations
   }
}
```

How can we identify first iteration in (1)?

Comment: Why do you only need the first iteration? Given that the properties are not guaranteed to be listed in a predictable order, what is it that you're doing?

Comment: I'd like check object has at least one property or not. Object.keys - good solution but it not supported IE8. I compile url from js object - for first element need add '?' delimeter, for other '&'. Order of keys is not important for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you can, move it out of the loop:

```
do_one_time_thing();
for (var prop in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      // Other operations
   }
}
```

Otherwise, set a flag, and lower it after the first iteration:

```
var first_iteration = true;
for (var prop in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (first_iteration) {
          do_one_time_thing();
          first_iteration = false;
      }
      // Other operations
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't move it out of the loop because I need check whether the object has at least one property. fardjad proposed solution for getting properties of object.

Answer (score 25):

you can use forEach

```
array.forEach((element,index) => {
    if(index==0){
        // first element
        }else{
          // not first element  
        }
      });
```

Comment: Make it even sexier with a ternary operator, if applicable: `(i == 0) ? doStuff() : doOtherStuff();`

Answer (score 5):

Since there's no loop counter, you need to track this yourself:

```
var first = true;

for (var prop in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) {
      if (first) {
        first = false;
        // Here need operation only for first iteration (1)
      }
      // Other operations
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if there is a solution without using the flag?

Comment: You'll need a flag *somewhere*. Without knowing what you want to do in there, it's hard to say more, or to understand why the flag is a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't care what the first item is, then you can use `Object.keys()` with `.forEach()` to avoid using a flag.

With this, you also don't need to use `.hasOwnProperty()`, because `Object.keys()` handles that for you.

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, i) {
   if (i === 0) {
      console.log("first", obj[key]);
   }
   console.log(obj[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Properties are not guaranteed to be listed in a predictable order (as others said).

So you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the object properties as an array, sort that array and get the first element:

```
var firstProperty = Object.keys(obj).sort()[0];
// firstValue = obj[firstProperty];
```

Comment: Object.keys - good solution but it [isn't supported in IE8](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.keys).